# Google Search Console API : HttpError 403 "Search Analytics load quota exceeded"

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-search-console

We have a daily python script that pulls search console information from the Google Search Console API. It's run for over a year with no problems. Then suddenly on January 6th 2020, we started getting 403 errors that stated we exceeded our load quota:

HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fwww..com/searchAnalytics/query?alt=json returned "Search Analytics load quota exceeded. Learn about usage limits: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/limits.">

I've played around with the requests to get them as basic as possible and I still get the 403 error saying I've exceeded my load quota. Even a request as simple as this fails:

request = {
      'startDate': '2020-01-20',
      'endDate': '2020-01-20',
      'dimensions': ['date']
  }

I've confirmed that this is not a credentials issue or a refresh token issue as we can hit other Google API's with our credentials just fine. I can even pull sitemaps from the Search Console API without issue (webmasters.sitemaps().list(siteUrl=site_url).execute()). However, any attempt to use webmasters.searchanalytics().query() results in a 403 regardless of how simple or basic the query request is.

I also checked our quotas and we're nowhere near being close to the max. For today, I show 20 requests against a 100,000,000 query max. Source: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/webmasters.googleapis.com/quotas

I also can't find any indication of api version issues or changes in supported features for search console queries against the API. Everything just stopped working on the 6th and I can't figure out why.

Has anyone else had this happen? Any ideas on where I can look for solutions?

NOTE: I am posting to stack overflow with these tags per Google's recommended way to get their attention: https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/support

Comment: were you able to find a workaround.